# How can I pass the bathroom part in the mission "Enter the Bank" undetected?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-3

I get in the bathroom through the window, but when the Iranian came in it said press <kbd>O</kbd>, then he says NOW and it says press <kbd>R1</kbd> but I just can't pass this part. I've tried hitting both constantly, then <kbd>O</kbd> first then <kbd>R1</kbd> then I try leaving both pressed. I don't know what else to do; I've try many things and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: are you sure you're pressing the correct buttons, e.g. you think it's one button but it is actually another? All the quick time events are simple, just press the correct button within the alotted time.

Answer (score 3):

**Hold**, don't tap, circle. When he says *now*, **tap** R1.